# Using Quartz for a scheduled task in a SpringMVC Maven Project - Need to verify crontab parameter

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
        <task:scheduled ref="userReg" method="copyUserInfo"
                        cron="0 6,23 * * * ?"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Using the following cron parameter, the scheduled task should run at 6AM and 11PM every day right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that will run at 6 and 23 minutes past every hour (Quartz cron expressions use seconds as their first field).

You want

```
0 0 6,23 * * ?
```

See [Cron Trigger tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html)